# Combining PullToRefreshListView and StickyHeaderListView, list view doesn't remember scroll position on fragment change

Tags: android, android-fragments, pull-to-refresh

I need a `ListView` that combines the functionality of a [PullToRefreshListView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) and a [StickyHeaderListView](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) by creating a class called PullToRefreshStickyListView which is an extension of [PullToRefreshBase](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/library/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/library/PullToRefreshBase.java) the class is here:

```
public class PullToRefreshStickyListView extends PullToRefreshBase<StickyListHeadersListView>{

public PullToRefreshStickyListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}   

public PullToRefreshStickyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase.Orientation getPullToRefreshScrollDirection() {
    return Orientation.VERTICAL;
}

@Override
protected StickyListHeadersListView createRefreshableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    StickyListHeadersListView view = new StickyListHeadersListView(context, attrs);
    return view;
}

@Override
protected boolean isReadyForPullEnd() {
    return false;
}

@Override
protected boolean isReadyForPullStart() {
    StickyListHeadersListView view = getRefreshableView();
    if (view.getWrappedList().getChildCount() == 0)
        return true;
    return view.getWrappedList().getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
}
}
```

All is fine, but my problem is, when the fragment that contains this class is shown for the first time, hidden, and shown again for a second time, the list view doesn't seem to remember its last vertical scroll position. Am I missing something? I'm thinking I should be doing something with onSaveInstance, but I am not overly familiar with this so I don't really know why. Maybe someone can give me pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I've discovered how to fix this. Turns out that a list view needs to have an ID in order for its scroll state to be remembered. I've just added this line in this method:

```
@Override
protected StickyListHeadersListView createRefreshableView(Context context, AttributeSet     attrs) {
    StickyListHeadersListView view = new StickyListHeadersListView(context, attrs);
    view.setId(R.id.sticky_header);
    return view;
}
```

created the file ids.xml in res, and added an id for the sticky header view like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="sticky_header"></item>
</resources>
```

and that certainly did the trick.

Remember kids, give your `ListView`s their own id's.